# Reporting Service 2005 c# Report Viewer Illegal Characters in path

Tags: c#, .net, reporting-services

I have a reporting services report that was designed in VS2010.
When using 'front end' report viewer and sqldatasource the report runs fine.
However, I am trying to change the reports datasource and parameters through the 'code behind'.  When I run the same report it throws this error 'Illegal characters in path'.
So far I have not been able to find a cause.  Below is the code behind...

Thanks for any and all assistance!!!

```
string strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WISCConnectionString"].ToString();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {



      getReport();





    }
    protected void getReport()
    {
        DataSet ds = getData();
        ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource();
        rds.Name = "ParameterCorpBillDate";
        rds.Value = ds.Tables["ParameterCorpBillDate"];
        rds.DataSourceId = "SqlDataSource1";

        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "Reports\rptPeriodAnalysisCorpBillDate.rdlc";
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();

        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);


        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
        ReportViewer1.Visible = true;
    }


    private DataSet getData()
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();


        SqlConnection sqlConnection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(strConnString);
        SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter();

        SqlCommand select = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("uspWRPeriodAnalysisCORP_BillDate_noparam");
        select.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        select.Connection = sqlConnection;

        //select.Parameters.Add("@custid", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "SON";
        //select.Parameters.AddWithValue("@period_startdt", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "01/01/2011";
        //select.Parameters.AddWithValue("@period_ENDdt", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "12/31/2011";

        dataAdapter.SelectCommand = select;

        dataAdapter.Fill(ds, "ParameterCorpBillDate");

        return ds;
    }
```

Comment: ReportPath = "Reports\\rptPeriodAnalysisCorpBillDate.rdlc"

Comment: Perfect!!! Its always the little things. THANKS!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From previous user assistance...
ReportPath = "Reports\rptPeriodAnalysisCorpBillDate.rdlc" – Hans Passant Sep 14 '11 at 21:49

escaping of backslash was over looked...